# When is $y=t^2$ not a solution of homogeneous second order differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How do I show that $y(t)=t^2$ can never be a solution of $y''+p(t)y'+q(t)y=0$ if $p(t)$ and $q(t)$ are continuous in $t=0$?

I haven't tried anything yet, because I simply do not know how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if

$y(t) = t^2, \tag{1}$

then

$y'(t) = 2t \tag{2}$

and

$y''(t) = 2. \tag{3}$

Inserting (1), (2), and (3) into

$y'' + p(t)y' + q(t)y = 0 \tag{4}$

yields

$2 + t(2p + qt) = 0, \tag{5}$

and now letting $t \rightarrow 0$ we see that (5) forces

$2 = 0, \tag{6}$

an obvious contradiction.  ***QED.***

Note we have used the continuity of $p(t)$ and $q(t)$ at $t = 0$ to establish that $t(2p(t) + tq(t)) \rightarrow 0$ as $t \rightarrow 0$.

Answer (score 2):

Or seen in another way, one has $y(0)=0=y'(0)$. Any initial value problem for a homogeneous ODE of order 2 with these initial conditions can only give the zero function as solution.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $y=t^2$ were a solution. Then
$$2 + 2tp(t)+t^2q(t) = 0$$
for all $t$. What happens as $t\to 0$?

Comment: Then you would have $tp,t^2q\rightarrow 0$?